# Error while querying various classes within root/webadministration namespace

Tags: iis-7, wmi

I am using a WMI query(using wbemtest):

```
select * from AuthenticationSection
```

using namespace `root/webadministration`, and I am getting the follwing error on a few servers (Windows Server 2008):

```
Number: 0x80041013 
Facility: Win32 Description:Provider Load Failure
```

On a few machines(Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008), I am also getting the following error:

```
Number: 0x80070003 
Facility: Win32 Description: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

The above mentioned errors are for reproduced for other classes like `HandlersSection`, `IsapiCgiRestrictionSection`, `GlobalModulesSection` etc. under the same namespace but also works on some servers (Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008)

Are there any kind of configuration settings that has to be set prior to running these queries?

I tried googling but could not find anything useful, highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

In order to query the `root/WebAdministration` namespace, you'll need to install the IIS7 WMI Provider.

On Windows Server 2008, you can install it by including the following IIS Role Service in Server Manager:

- Web Server Role

  - Role Services

    - Management Tools

      - IIS Management Scripts and Tools

[image]

To access the `root/MicrosoftIIsv2` namespace as well, tick of the "IIS 6 WMI Compatability" also

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the settings mentioned, these settings are already configured on the server, also I am able to connect to namespace root/webadministration. But when I try to query various classes such as Handlerssection, HTTPErrorsSection, AuthenticationSection, I get the following error:-
Number: 0x80070003
Facility: Win32
Description: The system cannot find the path specified.

On Some servers I was getting Provider load failure error as well